# How can I copy and paste outside of Neovim?

Tags: clipboard, neovim

I wanted to copy some code I have from Neovim to Firefox, but the stuff I yanked doesn't carry over outside Neovim.

After I checked `:checkhealth`, this what it said:

[image: :checkhealth output]

What should I do to handle this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to be able to paste text copied from Neovim to any app, you have to copy the text to the system clipboard. You can do that as follows:

0. Install a clipboard tool, because, as indicated in your screenshot, you don't have one installed.

   - If you are on an Xorg session, you may install either `xsel` or `xclip` by running:

     ```
     sudo apt install xsel
     ```

     or:

     ```
     sudo apt install xclip
     ```
   - If you are on a Wayland session, you may install `wl-clipboard` by running:

     ```
     sudo apt install wl-clipboard
     ```
1. Select the text you wish to copy in Neovim.
2. Press the following keys one at a time: `"+y`

   This copies (`y`) the selected text to the [selection register](https://learnvim.irian.to/basics/registers#the-selection-registers) (`"+`).
3. Paste the selected text to the app you wish to using the usual paste shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

To make things easier, you can also have the text you copy in Neovim always copied to the system clipboard by adding the following in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file (create the file if it doesn't exist or go to the correct file location if you use a custom Neovim setup):

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

If you are using the [Lua API](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html) for configuring Neovim, you can achieve the same using the command in [kkvamshee's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1503842/618353).

Comment: this worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested my nvim and my Copy/Paste/Mouse related config options from (~/.config/nvim/init.vim) are:

```
    set mouse=nv                 " middle-click paste with 
    set hlsearch                " highlight search 
    set clipboard+=unnamedplus   " using system clipboard
    # with these plugins
    call plug#begin("~/.vim/plugged")
    " Plugin Section
    Plug 'dracula/vim'
    Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
    " Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
    Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
    Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
    Plug 'preservim/nerdcommenter'
    Plug 'mhinz/vim-startify'
    Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
    call plug#end()
```

Now Copy works by double-clicking or clicking+draging the mouse to highlight your text selection, right-click then brings up a mini-menu with Copy, Paste, Etc.  Select Copy.

Now all of 1) middle-clicking, 2) right-clicking for the mini-menu again to select Paste & 3) the old staple option Ctrl+v will perform the Paste both inside another xfce4-terminal using nvim on a  text file or using Firefox on Ask Ubuntu to do this.

And Yeah, I saw the above post, I have xsel 1.2.1-1 installed.  If you need my entire nvim/init.vim config file just let me know.
Cheers, Jono

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by adding following line to your `init.lua` file, if you are using the [Lua API](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html) to configure Neovim:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_option("clipboard", "unnamed")
```